# converting regex to dfsa

Tags: regex

[image]

I am studying the process that converting regex to dfsa. 
I met a regex a|bc*d
and make a dfsa like that.

but the http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa

here it converts the regex like below. [image]

is there any difference between them? is my dfsa is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly yours contains a mistake because after matching `b`, the regex engine can match `d` right after as `c*` can match an empty string (`c` can be missing between `b` and `d`).

The `*` quantifier matches 0 or more occurrences of what the previous subpattern (group, character class, a literal character) can match.

```
 a|bc*d
0| || |
 1 || |
   || |
   2| |
    3 |
      4
```

Comment: I think that's why there is an option to go from 2 to 4 without going to 3? Is that wrong?

Comment: That is exactly why there is the "direct route" from `b` to `d` (from 2 to 4). `c*` is totally optional.

Comment: but mine also catch that c can be missed. I mean, if you are at state 2, fsa can simply doesn't read "c" and just go straight to d. If I understand right, even thought the generating strings are same, but regex "bc*d" should be fully interpreted. So, in my dfsa, it is possible to go right through b after d, not reading c. Did I understand right?

Comment: but...still I don't undertand exactly. In second picture. I don't understand why there is state 3. just looping in state2 and make direct node for d(like mine) would be enough. isnt' it?

Comment: In your diagram, there is no place for `c`, your `c` is at the point where `b` is. First, `b` should be matched once. Then, there are two ways: either straight to `d`, or match `c` (zero or more times) and then `d`.

Comment: aha. so you mean in my dfsa, at state2, I can't read any c, right?

Comment: Never Mind, Got it. Thanks!